# Changing TD into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The html is above. I've tried many different ways to change Test2 into a link but have not succeeded. Test1 remains constant but Test2 changes. My goal is to change Test2 or whatever may be in the  (it changes) into a google search link that is clickable. So Test2 would become a link that is http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Test 2. jquery or javascript is fine.

Comment: Check it http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_wrap.asp

Comment: What did your unsuccessful attempts look like?

Comment: Why can't you put an actual link in the cell? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native Javascript functions:

```js
// Select the second TD (you might want to use an ID instead)
var myTD = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];

// Change its content
myTD.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' + myTD.textContent + '">'
               +     myTD.textContent
               + '</a>';
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jQuery:

```js
// Select the second TD (you might want to use an ID instead)
var myTD = $('td:eq(1)');

// Change its content
myTD.html('<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' + myTD.text() + '">'
        +     myTD.text()
        + '</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`html`**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method on the second `td` (0-based):

```js
$('td').eq(1).html(function(_, s) {
  return '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' + s + '">' + s + '</a>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice use of the `s` parameter, which makes it more concise.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = $('td:nth-child(2)')
$(test).wrapInner('<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=' + test.html() + '"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're wrapping an `<a>` element around the outside of a `<td>`. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, squint. Ok, I changed the code to `wrapInner()`

Comment: @squint, I was the upvoter, but I see your point!  The change to `wrapInner()` is clearly right.

Answer (score 0):

This will transform the cell into a clickable link when you click on the cell.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1y9vnvhf/)

```
$('td').click(function(){
    tmp = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<a href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q='+tmp+'" >'+tmp+'</a>');
});
```